# Proving the open disc in $\mathbb R^2$ is not closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to get use to calculating limit points in metric spaces, but am getting stuck.

Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

The set of all complex $z$ such that $|z| < 1$

I'm trying to show that this set is not closed.

To do this, I need to show that it doesn't contain all of its limit points. This means I need to show that there is some neighbourhood containing no point that is different to $p$ (say).

Let $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} < 1\}$

if I consider a neighbourhood $N_{r}(p) = \{q: d(p,q) < r\}$

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. I know ultimately that the limit point will be the value $1$. I've only managed to do limit points of some very simple examples such as $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$

Comment: Consider the point $\langle 1,0\rangle$. (Your title is missing **not** before **closed**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove that it is closed by proving that its complement is not open. Take $(1,0)\in D^\complement$. For each $r>0$, take $r'>0$ such that $r'<r$ and also that $r'<2$. Then $(1-r',0)\in D_r\bigl((1,0)\bigr)\cap D$. Therefore, $D_r\bigl((1,0)\bigr)\not\subset D^\complement$. This proves that $D^\complement$ is not an open set.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But did we mean that we can prove it is NOT closed, if the complement is not open?  (I accidentally forgot the not in the title of my post initially).

Comment: By definition, a set is closed if and only if its complement is open. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the sequence of points $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $a_n=(1-1/n,0)$. Then each $a_n\in D$, and you can easily show that $a_n\to(1,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. However, this point is not contained in the open unit disk - how does this relate to $D$ being closed?

Comment: Is this an alternative definition of limit point? I've not come across limit point questions involving sequences.

Comment: You can use this information to show that $(1,0)$ is a limit point of $D$ that is not contained in $D$, since for any $\varepsilon>0$ some $a_n$ satisfies $d\big(a_n,(1,0)\big)<\varepsilon$ by the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the boundary of $D$ are all limit points of $D$, i.e. the set:
$$
\partial D = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \: | \: \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 1\}.
$$
Let's pick $(1,0) \in \partial D$. In order for $(1,0)$ to be a limit point of $D$, any neighborhood of $(1,0)$ must contain a point of $D$ different from $(1,0)$. Observe that $(1,0) \not \in D$, so we just need to show $N_\varepsilon (1,0) \cap D$ is nonempty for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Evidently, we have:
$$
\Big(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0\Big) \in D, 
$$
as $\sqrt{(1-\varepsilon/2)^2 + 0} = 1-\varepsilon/2 < 1$. Moreover,
$$
\Big(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0\Big) \in N_\varepsilon(1,0),
$$
since $\big|(1,0) - (1-\varepsilon/2, 0)\big| = \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon$. Thus, the intersection $N_\varepsilon(1,0) \cap D$ in nonempty for any $\varepsilon > 0$, and so $(1,0)$ is a limit point of $D$ not contained in $D$. So $D$ cannot be a closed set.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I understand it, but have one quick follow up question. How do we know that the boundary are all of the limit points? I would intuitively guess this is correct, as usually limit points are on the edge / boundary of a set. But I wouldn't be able to explain why this is the case.

Comment: Well in general it is not true that boundary points are limit points, which is why I started with "in this case..." As an example, consider the set $A = (0,1) \cup \{2\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The point $2 \in A$ is a boundary point, but not a limit point. Can you see why?

Comment: The point $2 \in A$ is a boundary point because it lies on the edge of the set (I'm not sure how to explain mathematically why). It is not a limit point because I could take a ball  with radius say $\frac{1}{2}$ then $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(2)$ doesn't contain any element of $A$?

Comment: Yes that would be correct. To make "the edge of a set" more mathematical, we say $x$ is a boundary point of $A$ if, for any neighborhood $N(x)$ of $x$, we have $N(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $N(x) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$, where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$.